# CloudFormation template for Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I am trying to spin up a Aurora PostgreSQL instance in AWS using CloudFormation. I want to pass in security groups as parameters to the "VpcSecurityGroupIds" in "DBCluster" Resource. Here is what I have currently -

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Aurora PostgreSQL",
"Parameters": {
      "DBSecurityGroupIds": {
            "Description": "Security groups for PostgreSQL",
            "Type": "String"
    },
.....
"Resources": {
    "DBCluster": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
                { "Ref" : "DBSecurityGroupIds" } 
            ]
        }
    },
.....
    "RDSinstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
    },
    "RDSinstance2": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
    }
.....
}
```

How do I specify a list of Security Groups when running this template? I want it to look something like this (I had it hardcoded earlier like this)

```
"VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
                "sg-xxxxxx",
                "sg-xxxxxx"
            ]
```

I did try Fn:Join but keep getting Invalid Security Group errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -

```
"VpcSecurityGroupIds": 
                { "Fn::Split" :[ "," , {"Ref" : "DBSecurityGroupIds" } ] 
                }
```

did the trick!